# What does tf.global_variables_initializer() do under the hood?

Tags: python, tensorflow

There have been many cases ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45047589/tensorflow-fully-connected-not-working-in-unit-test-cases/45047635#45047635) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44584809/why-this-tensorflow-tutorial-code-not-working/44585267#44585267)) of TensorFlow users adding

```py
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

before defining any variables or operations and then getting an error along the lines of

```
Attempting to use uninitialized value
```

There is an explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44433438/understanding-tf-global-variables-initializer) but it makes no mention of the underlying `tf.global_variables_initializer` calls. It's almost copying TF API wholesale. This question focuses on the fact that there are still uninitialized values when some users call `sess.run(init_op)`. Example code and an analysis into what `tf.global_variables_initializer` would be great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding tf.global\_variables\_initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44433438/understanding-tf-global-variables-initializer)

Comment: This question is different from what you linked. Added the focus of this question above.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The TensorFlow API has a very short section on [`tf.global_variables_initializer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/global_variables_initializer). It simply mentions:

> This is just a shortcut for `variable_initializer(global_variables())`.

Tracing it to [`tf.variables_initializer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variables_initializer), we can see that the usage of this function is as such:

`tf.variables_initializer(var_list, name='init')`

This means that we are implitcitly passing `tf.global_variables` as a `var_list` into `tf.variables_initializer`. If we have not defined any variables before calling `tf.global_variables_initializer`, `var_list` is essentially empty. The code below illustrates this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default():
  # Nothing is printed
  for v in tf.global_variables():
    print v

  init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
  a = tf.Variable(0)
  b = tf.Variable(0)
  c = tf.Variable(0)

  # 3 Variables are printed here
  for v in tf.global_variables():
    print v

  with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    print sess.run(a)
```

The 3 variables printed out are as such:

```
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=int32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'Variable_1:0' shape=() dtype=int32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'Variable_2:0' shape=() dtype=int32_ref>
```

Running the above code as is would result in an error along the lines of what's mentioned above:

```
Attempting to use uninitialized value
```

Swapping the position of `init_op` to after `a b c`:

```py
  a = tf.Variable(0)
  b = tf.Variable(0)
  c = tf.Variable(0)
  init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

would make it work.

Comment: I'm using tf 1.15 and `tf.variables_initializer` is not available any more. Instead, `tf.global_variables_initializer()`  equals to `tf.initialize_variables(var_list=tf.global_variables())`

Answer (score 6):

The doc has actually a pretty detailed and useful [section about variable initialization](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables#initialization). You learn in particular that

> Variable initializers must be run explicitly before other ops in your model can be run. The easiest way to do that is to add an op that runs all the variable initializers, and run that op before using the model. (..) Use `tf.global_variables_initializer()` to add an op to run variable initializers.

So basically `tf.global_variables_initializer()` go through all your variables, and call

```
sess.run(my_var.initializer)
```

`tf.global_variables_initializer()` does this automatically and at once. This function is a time-saver but technically you do not *have* to call it and could initialize your variables by other means (most frequent example: restoring weights from file).

How does it have knowledge of all variables? By default, when a `Variable` is created, it is added to tensorflow's `GLOBAL_VARIABLES` collection. So `global_variables_initializer` is basically iterating through the variables of this collection and calling their initializer.

However `Variable` let you choose collections to place it into. Should you exclude your variable from `GLOBAL_VARIABLES`, the created variable will *not* get initialized by `tf_global_variables_initializer()`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(0)
my_vars = []
y = tf.Variable(0, collections=my_vars)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run() # does not initialize y!
print(x.eval())
# 0
print(y.eval())
# FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_2
```